# Comparing Two floating numbers with rounding in Java ( Big Java Ex 5.3)

Tags: java

I've read a bunch of questions on rounding numbers to n amount of decimal places and then I've found out using `BigDecimal` is pretty good
 However I'm having a bit of trouble with the following exercise in my book, Consider the following input and output

```
Enter two floating-point numbers:
2.0
1.99998

//output
They are the same when rounded to two decimal places.
They differ by less than 0.01.

Enter two floating-point numbers:
0.999
0.991

//output
They are different when rounded to two decimal places.
They differ by less than 0.01.
```

**MY CODE**

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String [] args ){
        Scanner getNum = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner getNumTwo = new Scanner(System.in);

        BigDecimal a = getNum.nextBigDecimal();
        float b = getNum.nextFloat();

        BigDecimal valBNew = new BigDecimal(b).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        BigDecimal valANew = a;
        System.out.println(valBNew); // 2.00
        System.out.println(a); //2.0
        if (valBNew == a){
            System.out.println("They are the same when rounded to two decimal places");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("They are different when rounded to two decimal places");
        }

    }
}
```

Heres my attempt. I'm having trouble using two floats and then using big decimal. And then i'm having issues with my if statement since `2.0` isnt the same as `2.00`.

Whats my best option here? I'd like to get the rounding part working then the difference will be easy.

Comment: Have you tried `valBNew.equals(a)`?

Comment: Why .equals? I just studied that this chapter and it said to use it for comparing strings only

Comment: Because you have objects. Strings are also objects.

Comment: It doesent work I just tried

Comment: Your question is confusing. The output you quote is not the output your program actually produces (for a start, you are not showing the outputs "2.0" and "2.00" produced by your println). Also, you include many irrelevant statements such as "Scanner getNumTwo = ..." which shouldn't be there at all. Can you please edit and clean it up, so we can understand the question better?

Comment: The first snippet is the answer. My code below just added those to test why they werent being set equal ( hence the two system.out.println). Anyways compareTo fixed it all. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [BigDecimal documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

> `public int compareTo(BigDecimal val)`
>
> Compares this `BigDecimal` with the specified `BigDecimal`. Two `BigDecimal` objects that are equal in value but have a different scale (like 2.0 and 2.00) are considered equal by this method.

Whereas, for `.equals`

> `public boolean equals(Object x)`
>
> Compares this `BigDecimal` with the specified `Object` for equality. Unlike `compareTo`, this method considers two `BigDecimal` objects equal only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 when compared by this method).

Therefore, this is correct

```
if (valBNew.compareTo(a) == 0) {

}
```

Comment: Because `if` statements need a boolean conditional? `compareTo` returns an `int`?

Comment: @cresjoy `x.compareTo(y)` returns `0` when `x == y`, `1` when `x > y` and `-1` when `x < y`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @cricket_007 -s answer, this is how a clean solution would look like:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args ) {
        try (Scanner getNum = new Scanner(System.in)) { // try-with-resources, e.g. it auto-closes the scanner
            double a = Double.parseDouble(getNum.next()); // parsing a number from a line
            double b = Double.parseDouble(getNum.next());

            BigDecimal valBNew = new BigDecimal(b); // 2.00, no rounding
            BigDecimal valANew = new BigDecimal(a); // 2.0
            if (valBNew.compareTo(valANew) == 0) { // this is the magic
                System.out.println("They are the same");
            } else {
                System.out.println("They are different");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `b` are both floating point types, then

`(long)(a * 100 + 0.5) == (long)(b * 100 + 0.5)`

is an adequate test for 2-decimal-place-rounding equality, subject to your not overflowing the `long` type, and your being able to tolerate the limitations of binary floating point. The `0.5` constants implement the German rounding.

Comment: I see, anyway we can use bigdecimal here? Because the way I do it you can get up to n decimal places